# Вопрос по чтению из файлов и записи в переменную по словам

Tags: python, python-3.x

И так, у меня вопрос:
В python(3.9.2) я пытаюсь сделать так чтобы при запуске программы из файла читались слова (так же при чтении они проходят перекодировку из формата Windows 1251 в Utf-8, для правильного выведения), и поочередно слово за словом (вместе с символом слово(с символом не тем что разделяет строки(\n))) записывалось в переменную и тут же эта переменная выводила на экран (который в свою очередь будет создан в библиотеке Pygame, из-за чего я собираюсь сделать это все в 1 цикле While) это слово и записывало следующее, и что-бы все это выведение на экран происходило с паузами в 1 секунду (собственно без использования функции time.sleep()).
Заранее благодарю.

Comment: посмотрите на pygame.time.set_timer()

Comment: Извините пожалуйста, но мне в основе нужно бы как поочередно выводить слова, чтоб они не кучей вываливались на экран, ну а про задержку благодарю .